# Custom IRibbon in Excel does not show up when file on network

Tags: excel, ribbon

I have an excel file saved as .xlsm that has a custom ribbon bar coded in XML. This was added to the customUI folder inside the .xlsm file and works beautifully from my home computer however when I take this file to work and put it on the network the custom ribbon bar does not appear at all. At home I am running 2016 and at work 2013, both on windows 10 x64 but both 13 and 16 have the capability to have custom ribbon bars with xml coding so I am at a loss for what is preventing this bar from showing up. Any help and solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One computer might be running a 32bit Excel and another might be running 64bit Excel, different than OS bit

Answer (score 0):

Check for any ribbon UI errors. You can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear.

1. Start the application.
2. Click the File tab.
3. Click Options.
4. In the categories pane, click Advanced.
5. In the details pane, select Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors, and then click OK.

Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) article.

Also check out the Trust Center settings. Are they the same on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my company follows guidelines based on a Security Technical Implementation Guides, unfortunately we were using an older version that specifically prevents the use of custom UI.  Hope this helps someone in the future.